# How to save a tokenizer after training it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I have just followed [this](https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/examples/tokenizer_training.ipynb) tutorial on how to train my own tokenizer.

Now, from training my tokenizer, I have wrapped it inside a Transformers object, so that I can use it with the transformers library:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast

new_tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast(tokenizer_object=tokenizer)
```

Then, I try to save my tokenizer using this code:

```
tokenizer.save_pretrained('/content/drive/MyDrive/Tokenzier')
```

But I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'tokenizers.Tokenizer' object has no attribute 'save_pretrained'
```

Am I saving the tokenizer wrongly?

If so, what is the correct approach to save it to my local files, so that I can use it later?

Comment: shouldn't be `new_tokenizer` instead of `tokenizer`?

Comment: I have used `tokenizer.save(directory + "/" + fname)` successfully.

Comment: @OmG is right. It's confusing but `tokenizers.Tokenizer` does not have `save_pretrained()` method. `transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer` does.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a custom tokenizer, you can save & load it like this:

```
from tokenizers import Tokenizer

# Save
tokenizer.save('saved_tokenizer.json')

# Load
tokenizer = Tokenizer.from_file('saved_tokenizer.json')
```

`save_pretrained()` only works if you train from a pre-trained tokenizer like this:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

old_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("the_pretrained_model_in_hf")
tokenizer = old_tokenizer.train_new_from_iterator(get_training_corpus(), 52000)
tokenizer.save_pretrained("your-tokenizer")
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same trouble, you have to save the tokenizer in a directory as well as his config file. In addition in the same directory you should have the config of your model. Like the following:

```
#after the training
tokenizer.save('folder/tokenizer.json')

import json

#tokenizer config
tokenizer_config = {"max_len": 512, "name_or_path": "tokenizer_name"}

with open("folder/tokenizer_config.json", 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(tokenizer_config, fp)

#model config, in the same tokenizer folder
config = {
    "architectures": [
        "RobertaForMaskedLM"
    ],
    "attention_probs_dropout_prob": 0.1,
    "hidden_act": "gelu",
    "hidden_dropout_prob": 0.1,
    "hidden_size": 768,
    "initializer_range": 0.02,
    "intermediate_size": 3072,
    "layer_norm_eps": 1e-05,
    "max_position_embeddings": 40000, #512, changed to 40000
    "model_type": "roberta",
    "num_attention_heads": 12,
    "num_hidden_layers": 6,
    "type_vocab_size": 1,
    "vocab_size": 30 #30522, changed to 30 rostlab aminoacid vocabulary
}

with open("folder/config.json", 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(config, fp)
```

Then you should use the folder path when you call the tokenizer:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('./folder')
```

Hope it helps! I spent a lot of time as well trying to understand how to make it works

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode the values in the configs.

Answer (score -2):

The documentation for `BertTokenizerFast` suggests using `_save_pretrained()`.

See here: https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#transformers.BertTokenizerFast.save_vocabulary